# MySql Query - INSERT INTO command but only without duplicates

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have this workable query which is inserting proper data into 'selections' table according to some conditions:

```
INSERT INTO selections (auctionid, selections.order)
VALUES 
((SELECT id FROM auctions, game WHERE auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID), 1,
((SELECT id FROM auctions, game WHERE auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID), 2,
((SELECT id FROM auctions, game WHERE auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID), 3
```

but my problem is how to improve this query to prevent getting same duplicates in table when running this query?

Selections table have 3 columns: id, auctionid, order  where id is autoincrement number generated for each new record.

So auctionid and order shouldn't be the same values in record.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: do you mean that for a given row, `auctionid` and `order` have to be different?

Comment: auctionid and order (combination of both in one record) should be different. Example: If have auctionid 12345 and order 1 it should add new record with for example: 12345 and 2 or 55555 and 1 but not with 12345 and 1 as those would be duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UNIQUE INDEX` to the `(auctionid, order)` pair.

```
ALTER TABLE selections ADD UNIQUE index_name (`auctionid`, `order`)
```

And when you insert you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` so that it ignores duplicates instead of throwing an error. (Useful when you batch insert and the duplicates are expected)

Comment: I tryed to get this query for adding unique index but receiving this error:           `[SQL] ALTER TABLE selections ADD UNIQUE index_name (auctionid, order)

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order)' at line 1`

Comment: Oh that's because `ORDER` is a reserved word in MYSQL. I edited my answer. All you need is to do is add backticks to the column names.

Comment: Was working at first. I am not receiving any error. But now don't understand why getting `Affected rows: 0` when query should add records in `selection` table as in `auction` table there are new records with new `id`!

Comment: Hmm. Simply not working! Is there a way of solving this without this UNIQUE INDEX aproach?      My code: `INSERT IGNORE INTO selections (auctionid, selections.order, title, odds, startamount)
VALUES 
((SELECT id FROM auctions, game WHERE auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID...`  simply not working right :( adding only zeros to auctionID column and not adding those which need...

Comment: Well, I see now `UNIQUE INDEX` rule is working fine. Just my `INSERT IGNORE INTO` not working :/  Adding only first 3 records with zeros to `selections` table (and only for first time with help of UNIQUE INDEX. Other data from `auctions` and `game` tables don't want to insert. Just getting `Affected rows: 0`. Please help to get this.

Comment: That's because your `SELECT`s are not right. They return more than one row so it won't work. See my answer to your other question. I didn't have the time to write the PHP solution for you but google around PHP and MySQL there are countless resources to help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Created 3 separated queries for each row, working for now!

So with added UNIQUE INDEX to the (auctionid, order) pair have this workable code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
selections
(
selections.auctionid,
selections.order,
selections.title,
startamount
)
SELECT
auctions.id,
1,
PlayerA,
0.01
FROM
auctions, game
WHERE
auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID
;

INSERT IGNORE INTO
elections
(
selections.auctionid,
selections.order,
selections.title,
startamount
)
SELECT
auctions.id,
2,
PlayerB,
0.01
FROM
auctions, game
WHERE
auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID
;

INSERT IGNORE INTO
selections
(
selections.auctionid,
selections.order,
selections.title,
startamount
)
SELECT
auctions.id,
3,
'third text',
0.01
FROM
auctions, game
WHERE
auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID
;
```